# Webpack 2 - redundant bundle file after text extract

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, extract-text-plugin

Here's a public Gist of my Webpack configuration, which is essentially a slightly modified Webpack config ejected from Angular CLI:

https://gist.github.com/sparkbuzz/3cd017671751083e2af8c10a1ad37747

This Webpack build is generating *styles.bundle.css* AND *styles.bundle.js*, but *styles.bundle.js* contain commented lines that read:

```
// removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin
```

The *styles.bundle.js* file is completely redundant as the extract plugin removed all it's contents and dumped it in *styles.bundle.css* as expected.

**How can I avoid loading *styles.bundle.js*, as the *styles.bundle.css* file is loaded from a link inside my resulting *index.html*.**

In *webpack.config.js* there are two instances of the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin):

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractMainCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].bundle.css');
const extractSplashCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('splash.css');
```

There's an entry point for styles that is the reason for having *styles.bundle.js*:

```
    styles: [
        "./src/styles/styles.scss",
        "./src/styles/vendor.scss"
    ],
```

Then some rules to generate *splash.css* and *styles.bundle.css*

```
{
    include: [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/splash.scss")
    ],
    exclude: [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/styles.scss"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/vendor.scss")
    ],
    test: /.scss$/,
    loaders: extractSplashCSS.extract({
        use: [
            'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
            'sass-loader'
        ]
    })
},
{
    exclude: [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/styles.scss"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/vendor.scss"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/splash.scss")
    ],
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [
        "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
        "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
        "postcss-loader",
        "sass-loader"
    ]
},
{
    exclude: [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/splash.scss"),
    ],
    include: [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/styles.scss"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src/styles/vendor.scss")
    ],
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: extractMainCSS.extract({
        use: [
            "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
            "postcss-loader",
            "sass-loader"
        ]
    })
},
```

and the two instances of the extract plugin has been added to the plugins object:

```
plugins: [
    extractMainCSS,
    extractSplashCSS,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to revert the styles bundle to serve as an ordinary Webpack bundle on it's own, meaning no .css file.

I changed the loaders portion for my rule:

```
loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    use: [
        "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
        "postcss-loader",
        "sass-loader"
    ],
    /...
})
```

to the following:

```
loaders: [
        "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
        "postcss-loader",
        "sass-loader"
    ],
    /...
})
```

There was no need for text extraction here. What was important to me was that I managed to get the extraction and eventually, inlining of splash.css working correctly

I still want to see what happens with multiple instances and the disabled property set to different values on each.

Answer (score 3):

Webpack creates a bundle for each entry point. If you don't want to create a bundle, you have to include the CSS files in another entry point. `extract-text-webpack-plugin` will remove all CSS anyway, but if you think about it, the CSS should be part of the bundle where you use it, which in your case is probably `main`.

You can remove the `styles` entry and add the `.scss` files to the `main` entry:

```
main: [
    "./src/main.ts",
    "./src/styles/styles.scss",
    "./src/styles/vendor.scss"
]
```

To get the same name for the styles (`styles.bundle.css`) you also need to change your `extractMainCSS`.

```
const extractMainCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.bundle.css');
```